# My proof of divergence of $(-1)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

Should I shorten my proof?
  (Also, should I try to prove without contradiction?)

We consider the sequence
  $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$,
  where
  $x_n = (-1)^n$.

$\textbf{Lemma.}$
  For every element $x_n$ of the sequence $(x_n)$,
  we have $|x_n| = 1$.
  (We could prove this by induction on $n$.)

$\textbf{Theorem.}$
  $(x_n)$ diverges.

$\textit{Proof.}$
  We prove the theorem by contradiction.
  To that end,
  we assume that $(x_n)$ is not divergent, i.e. we assume that it is convergent.
  With that said, we are done as soon as a contradiction is deduced.
  By assumption, there is an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
  \begin{equation*}
    \forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}, \varepsilon > 0 :
    \exists N           \in \mathbb{N}                  :
    \forall n           \in \mathbb{N}, n > N           :
    |x_n - x| < \varepsilon .
  \end{equation*}
  We choose $\varepsilon = 1$.
  By assumption, there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
  \begin{equation*}
    \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n > N :
    |x_n - x| < 1 .
  \end{equation*}
  We choose $n = N + 1$.
  Hence, both $|x_n - x| < 1$ and $|x_{n + 1} - x| < 1$.
  Thus,
  \begin{equation*}
    |x_{n + 1} - x| + |x_n - x| < 2 .
  \end{equation*}
  Moreover,
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
      2 & =   |2| \\
        & =   |2| \cdot  1  \\
        & =   |2| \cdot |x_{n + 1}| && | \text{ by Lemma} \\
        & =   |2 x_{n + 1}| && | \text{ by multiplicativeness of abs. val.} \\
        & =   |x_{n + 1} + x_{n + 1}| \\
        & =   |x_{n + 1} + (-1)x_{n}| \\
        & =   |x_{n + 1} - x_{n}| \\
        & =   |x_{n + 1} + 0 - x_{n}| \\
        & =   |x_{n + 1} + (-x + x) - x_{n}| \\
        & =   |(x_{n + 1} - x) + (x - x_{n})| \\
        & \le |x_{n + 1} - x| + |x - x_{n}| && | \text{ by subadditivity of abs. val.} \\
        & =   |x_{n + 1} - x| + |x_{n} - x| \qquad && | \text{ by evenness of abs. val.} \\
    \end{split}
  \end{equation*}
  Hence, by transitivity, we have $2 < 2$.
  Obviously, we deduced a contradiction. QED

Comment: The question is if you should shorten your proof. That depends on what's the purpose of the proof.

Comment: A minor point: what is your definition of *sequence diverges*? Are you using *not converges* $\Leftrightarrow$ *diverges*? Because "diverges"  has some other meaning also and which is completely different from "not converges".

Comment: Shorter proofs of  divergence of $(-1)^n$ have been already added in answers. But this is the strangest one I have ever seen. I like it!

Comment: @Krish you are wrong

Comment: @user2345215: why? are you saying "not converges" and "diverges" are same?

Comment: @Krish Yes.​​​​

Comment: @Krish I think it depends on where you've studied. In my university (in italy) they told us that not convergent means the limit does not exists, divergent means the limit exists and it is $\infty$. Of course it is a matter of definition, but I prefer the way I've been taught as it is more informative that using divergent as synonymous of not convergent.

Comment: @Ant Wikipedia agrees with me. One uses diverges to $\infty$ to indicate what you say.

Comment: @user2345215 English wikipedia agrees with you. The italian page agrees with me. Now, english is the de facto standard and I'm cool with that, but it's worth pointing out that the consensus is not universal (or at least some confusion is possible!)

Comment: @user2345215: for my case, I use the same notation as *Ant* said. and I didn't say what was written is wrong. I just asked about the definition. (*A minor point*)

Comment: I am not sure if this has been said, but you don't need most of the first paragraph, anyone that reads this should understand what a contradiction is.

Comment: I have to agree with Kola, this proof is... interesting. The world needs more of those, because in my opinion this is a valuable skill  in mathematics.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following theorem: "If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit".

Answer (score 4):

I would shorten the proof.

Pick any $L \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $L \ge 0$, then we have $|x_n-L| \ge 1$ for all odd $n$. Hence $x_n$ does not converge to $L$.

If $L < 0$, then we have $|x_n-L| \ge 1$ for all even $n$. Hence $x_n$ does not converge to $L$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

The shortest proof of this would be to show that the sequence is not Cauchy, therefore cannot converge.   Let $\epsilon =1$.  Assume for contradiction sake that the sequence is cauchy, therefore there exists an $N$ such that for all $m\ge N,n\ge N,|a_n-a_m|<1$.  Thus, taking $n=N,m=N+1$, we have $|(-1)^N-(-1)^{N+1}|<1$,  but this is false, since this number is actually 2 (Since $N$ and $N+1$ have opposite parity).  Therefore it's not cauchy, hence it does not converge

Comment: hmm, subsequences is probably equally short, as the other answers :)

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how much you know about sequences but the shortest proof of the divergence of this sequence is that the two subsequences $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}$ that are constant therefore convergent do not converge to the same limit

Answer (score 2):

I think there are better ways to prove it.

> **Proposition A:** If $x_n$ converges, then the sequence of differences $x_{n+1}{-}x_n$ converges to $0$.
>
> **Proposition B:** If $x_n$ has subsequences $a_n$, $b_n$ which converge to different limits, then $x_n$ doesn't converge.

Either of these two immediately proves it and their proofs are no harder than what you are trying to do.

Take e.g. the first: For all $\varepsilon>0$ there's $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, $|x_n-L|<\varepsilon/2$, so for all $n\ge N$, $$|x_{n+1}-x_n|=|(x_{n+1}-L)-(x_n-L)|\le |x_{n+1}-L|+|x_n-L|\le\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2=\varepsilon.$$
Done!

Answer (score 2):

To give yet another answer - for any $n$, we have $\sup_{k\geqslant n} x_n=1$, so that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n = 1$, while $\inf_{k\geqslant n} x_n=-1$, so that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n=-1$. Since $\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n\neq\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n$, the sequence does not converge.

Answer (score 2):

We shall assume that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges and reach a contradiction. Let $L$ denote the number the sequence converges to, and set $\hat{\varepsilon}=\frac{1}{2}$. By definition there is $\hat{n} \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|x_n-L|<\hat{\varepsilon}$ whenever $n \geq \hat{n}$. Hence $|x_{\hat{n}}-x_{\hat{n}+1}| \leq |x_{\hat{n}}-L|+|L-x_{\hat{n}+1}|<1$. This is a contradiction as clearly $|x_{\hat{n}}-x_{\hat{n}+1}|=2$. Therefore the sequence does not converge.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$ x_{2n} = (-1)^{2n} = 1 \to 1,$$

and

$$ x_{2n+1} = (-1)^{2n+1} = (-1)(-1)^{2n} = -1 \to -1.$$

Therefore, $x_n$ is divergent.